# results from simulate.MixMod() function of MixMod Methods GLMMadaptive and phi parameters from mixed.model() function

Tags: mixed-model, glmmadaptive

I am using the function mixed.model() from package GLMMadaptive for fitting a Gamma Generalised Linear Mixed Model,of the form
[image: gamma glm]  where I take **log$\mu_{i}$**=**$\beta^{t}x_{i}$** + $v_{i}$ that is a Gamma GLMM with random effects for each sample denoted by $v_{i}$ where $v_{i}$$\sim$N(0,$\sigma^{2}$),where **$x_{i}$** is the vector of predictors for the $i^{th}$ sample.  Here is the output of summary function
summary(glmer_pred)

Call:
mixed_model(fixed = gene~peak2+peak9+peak11+peak18+peak25+peak26+peak27+peak30, random = ~1 | cells, data = workset_pos_glmer, family = Gamma(link = "log"))

[image]

My first question is what is the denoted by the phi_1 estimate in phi parameters,is it the same as $\phi$ in my model..?

Next I use the simulate() function from MixMod Methods of GLMMadaptive-
simulate(glmer_pred, nsim = 1, seed = NULL,type = "subject_specific", acount_MLEs_var = FALSE, sim_fun = NULL,sandwich = FALSE,new_RE = TRUE), and check the the kolmogrov smirnov test result with the original data.[image], I was happy to find the result p-value is non significant,however next I use the inverse of of the obtained phi_1 estimate from the fitted model and random effects variance estimate and simulate and check the kolmogrov smirnov results.[image]
I found the p-value is significant. So where am I getting the fitted model wrong, or what is the difference between simulate() and my method,am I interpreting the phi_ output as wrong from the fitted model(which  relates to my first question).
I also checked the source code of the package from github-https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/master/R/methods.R,and figured out it calls the family$simulate with new simulated random effects according to the arguements.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this line: https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/a25e1c92cabb3c8e3e5985995d4229e96f6cec42/R/Fit_Funs.R#L1329C16-L1329C70

The shape parameter of the gamma distribution is $\exp(\phi)$ and the scale $\mu / \exp(\phi)$.

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code and output. It is difficult to read. Just post the actual text delimited by three backticks and the system will format it properly.

Comment: Respected Professor @DimitrisRizopoulos thanks for your help,I checked the link,and from my understanding,**phis** denotes log(shape) parameter in gamma GLMM,and estimation and further functions work according to it.I wrote a short code on my own for simulating response - by taking,shape=exp(fitted object[["phis"]]),$\sigma^{2}$=sqrt(as.numeric(fitted object[["D"]])), simulating random effects by $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ and taking `scale=(exp((X%*%as.vector(fitted object[["coefficients"]]) + simulated randomeffects))/shape)`,and simulated using rgamma,is this equivalent to using simulate() function?

Comment: Just to add, I did Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with observed response and my simulation and found the results satisfactory -`ks.test(simulate(fittedobject, nsim = 1, seed = NULL,type = "subject_specific", acount_MLEs_var = FALSE, sim_fun = NULL,sandwich = FALSE,new_RE = TRUE),workset_pos$gene), D = 0.03576, p-value = 0.6986` and then simulating on my own and checking the ks.test results `ks.test((rgamma(length(workset_pos$gene), shape = n , scale =scale_sim   )   ),workset_pos$gene) D = 0.038314, p-value = 0.6136 `,(in order to confirm with the results of simulate())

Comment: That codes that simulates from the model is given here: https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/a25e1c92cabb3c8e3e5985995d4229e96f6cec42/R/Fit_Funs.R#L1349

Comment: Yes Sir I have noted it and(probably) that part is being called here -[(https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/a25e1c92cabb3c8e3e5985995d4229e96f6cec42/R/methods.R#L1374)] when using simulate() function from methods, I just wanted to check whether calling simulate(newRE=TRUE) and using the obtained parameters for simulation,as given in my previous comment are equivalent,I suppose they are.